# basic Python question: Slicing backward (-1) behaves differently depending on string length. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.4.4 Console

Why does the length of the string retrieved from the back change?

```
>>> word = 'abcde'
>>> len(word)//2
2
>>>word[:len(word) // 2:1]
'ab'
>>>word[:len(word) // 2:-1]
'ed'

>>> word = 'abcd'
>>> len(word)//2
2
>>> word[:len(word) // 2:1]
'ab'
>>> word[:len(word) // 2:-1]
'd'                  <-------- why only one character? should be 'dc'?
```

Comment: one word has 5 letters, the other has 4.. Maybe this is why?

Comment: Yes its the length difference, but how is does it behave differently. If you see, the Floor Division (//) always gives us 2 as a result. So two characters from the back should always be just that. How does it differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that slicing works in the following notation: list[start_position:end_position:step_length]
Thus in your code word[:len(word) // 2:1] you basically say: Get me characters from the beginning of the line (nothing is put before the first colon) till the character in position #2 (len(word)//2) with the step of 1 (process every first character in initial string)
And in word[:len(word) // 2:-1] you do the same but process string from the end (because of the step being set to -1) so you receive e and d (all characters from the end to the character in position #2)
And when word was equal to 'abcd' character with the position of 2 was 'c' thus all characters from the end till said position was 'd'

If you want to just grab the last two characters use: print('abcde'[-2:]) (in the initial order) and print('abcde'[:-3:-1]) in reverse. If you want all characters from the middle position till the end use print(word[mid:])

Hope that makes sense, and sorry from my English.

Comment: thank you Artem, i did not realize that the index of the characters would remain static and will not reverse inspite of the change in direction caused by step_length=-1.

Comment: "print(word[mid:])" ... does not work in python 3.4.4 ... does it work in any other version?

Comment: It works in 3.6 and what kind of error does it produce in 3.4?

Comment: in Python 3.4.4 -- 
>>> print(word[mid:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mid' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that you should define mid just use:
mid = len(word)//2 and then print(word[mid:])